# Canvas over Image - different size of drawn controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, canvas

My XAML is:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
            <Viewbox Name="viewBox"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="image" />
                    <Canvas Name="canvas" />
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
```

As you can see I have Canvas and Image controls in Grid to perform drawing over Image.

All images that I'm loading has the same dpi - 72.

When image was loaded I fetch some data and perform drawing:

```
var ellipse = new Ellipse
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 100,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    StrokeThickness = 1
                };
            canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, 10);
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, 10);
```

But it appears that ellipses look differently on different images. Its size depends on size of loaded image. If loaded image has large resolution - ellipse is small. If loaded image has small resolution - ellipse is too big.

How can I draw ellipses that has same physical size?

I've tried to apply SnapsToDevicePixels property on ellipse control but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the Image control and hence the inner Grid always get the size of the loaded image. The Viewbox then scales everything to fit into the outer Grid (cell). Obviously that also scales the Canvas and its child elements by the same scaling factor. Therefore you observe differently sized ellipses when loading images of different sizes.

The solution is not to use a Viewbox. The Image control already scales the displayed image, unless you set its [`Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx) property to `None`. Therefore you don't need a Viewbox at all. You should just give the Image control an appropriate size by setting either its `Width` or its `Height`, or perhaps both.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="image" Width="120" />
    <Canvas Name="canvas" />
</Grid>
```